# Isometries on a Banach space converging pointwise

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, isometry

I'm trying to find a Banach space $V$ with closed unit ball $B$ and a sequence of isometries $(f_n:V\to V)$ such that $(f_n)$ converges pointwise in $B$ but not uniformly in $B$.

My first attempts were to make it kind of simple. If $V=c_0$ (the space with sequences $x_n\to 0$ with the sup norm) take for instance the linear functions $T_n(x)=(0,\ldots,0,x_{n+1},x_{n+2},\ldots)$. It is easy to see that $T_n$ converges pointwise to the zero function, but it doesn't so uniformly in $B$. However, $T_n$ is not an isometry although it satisfies $\left\|{T(x)}\right\|\le\left\|{x}\right\|$.

Can someone give me a hint?

Thanks.

Comment: Would anything involving the shift operator work? $T(x_1,x_2,\ldots) = (0,x_1,x_2,\ldots)$ and $T_n:=T^n$. Thinking for a few minutes I can't come up with an appropriate space but perhaps it can work.

Comment: @user25959 I thought about that too, but I don't know if it converges pointwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $V=l^{2}, f_n(x_1,x_2,...))=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n,0,x_{n+1},...)$  (where a $0$ is inserted at the n-th position). Then $f_n(x) \to x$ for every $x \in B$ but $\|f_n(x)-x\|^{2}\geq |x_{n+1}|^{2}$ so the convergence is not uniform on $B$.

Comment: $f_n$ are supposed to be isometries

Comment: @user25959 I have revised my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: It is even possible to construct isometric bijections -- just swap $x_n$ and $x_{2n}$ in the sequence $x_n$ to define $f_n$.